# Makefiles compiling files even when nothing is changed

Tags: makefile

I am trying to create a makefile, for a small shell I am writing.
The files are:

```
myShell.c
myShellFunc.c
parser.y
shel.l
```

The makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS= -g -Wall


myshell: myShell.o myShellFunc.o parser.tab.o lex.yy.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) myShell.o myShellFunc.o parser.tab.o lex.yy.o -lfl -o myshell

myShell.o: myShell.c myShell.h parser.tab.h
myShellFunc.o: myShellFunc.c myShell.h

parser.tab.c: bisonfiles
parser.tab.h: bisonfiles
lex.yy.c: shell.l
    flex shell.l

.PHONY: bisonfiles
bisonfiles: parser.y
    bison -d parser.y
```

The problem is that even when there's no change in the files, it compiles them anyway.

When I run `make` for the first time, I get this:

```
bison -d parser.y
gcc -g -Wall   -c -o myShell.o myShell.c
gcc -g -Wall   -c -o parser.tab.o parser.tab.c
flex shell.l
gcc -g -Wall   -c -o lex.yy.o lex.yy.c
gcc -g -Wall myShell.o myShellFunc.o parser.tab.o lex.yy.o -lfl -o myshell
```

The second time I run it, without changing anything:

```
bison -d parser.y
gcc -g -Wall   -c -o parser.tab.o parser.tab.c
gcc -g -Wall myShell.o myShellFunc.o parser.tab.o lex.yy.o -lfl -o myshell
```

The third time I run it without changing anything:

```
bison -d parser.y
gcc -g -Wall   -c -o myShell.o myShell.c
gcc -g -Wall   -c -o parser.tab.o parser.tab.c
gcc -g -Wall myShell.o myShellFunc.o parser.tab.o lex.yy.o -lfl -o myshell
```

Why is this happening, when I haven't made any changes?
How do I write the makefile properly?

Comment: "*A phony target should not be a prerequisite of a real target file; if it is, its recipe will be run every time `make` goes to update that file.*" https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets

Comment: I removed the phony target, and it worked like expected. Thank you. Funny thing is I did read on it, in the manual, I guess I didn't understand it right the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets)...

> A phony target should not be a prerequisite of a real target file; if
>   it is, its recipe will be run every time make goes to update that
>   file.

But you have...

```
parser.tab.c: bisonfiles
parser.tab.h: bisonfiles
lex.yy.c: shell.l
        flex shell.l

.PHONY: bisonfiles
bisonfiles: parser.y
        bison -d parser.y
```

Here `bisonfiles` has been declared a `.PHONY` target and, hence, you're seeing `bison -d parser.y` being run on every `make` invocation.

The simplest solution is probably to get rid of the `bisonfiles` target completely and just use a pattern rule...

```
%.tab.c %.tab.h: %.y
        bison -d $<
```

Comment: You don't want this rule because it could run bison twice if you run make with `-j`.  An explicit rule with multiple targets defines multiple rules, one for each target.  You want a pattern rule here, which defines that all targets are built with a single invocation of the recipe.

Comment: @MadScientist Forgot about that.  Thanks for the correction.